If each person owns one house, should I say: Five people live in [a house or houses]?


These five people live in houses.
These five people live in a house.


Each of them only lives in one house, but the second sentence can also be understood as all five of them live together in a single house. So, what should I say? I'm trying to point out the type of accommodation these people live in.
I constantly run into this situation and always have to spend some time deciding which I should use, not to mention the fact that I'm not sure which one is correct even after considering. Some other similar cases are:


I've run through around 30 examples in 3 dictionaries and 90% of them include the word solely preceding a preposition; 9%, an adjective; and only 3%, a verb.


Should I change it to "prepositions", "adjectives", and "verbs"?


There was an increase in the proportion of people who chose the university because of its proximity to their parental home. (Or should it be "homes"?)


P.S. I feel that the choice of plural and singular in these cases has something to do with whether I'm talking about the type of thing or the thing(s). I expanded on this under James's answer.

(2) would normally be understood to mean that they all live together.

What about 60% of the population here live in a house? I think we can only interpret this sentence as each person in that 60% lives in a house. I wonder if "houses" changes the meaning of the sentence.

Personally, I would still prefer "60% of the population live in houses." The phrasing "60% of the population live in a house" would be understood, but only because the more natural interpretation is so unimaginable that it's instantly dismissible

to their parent's home.

People who live in glass houses ___

OP's sentence and my comments in italics.
1.These five people live in houses.
(This sentence is correct. Famous proverb - People who live in glass houses should not throw stones at others..
For more clarity you can say- These five people live in their own houses).
2.These five people live in a house.
(It means all' five people live in one single house.
Correct - Each of them lives in their own house.).
3.I've run through around 30 examples in 3 dictionaries and 90% of them include the word solely preceding a preposition; 9%, an adjective; and only 3%, a verb.
(This sentence is correct as it is. No change required).
4.There was an increase in the proportion of people who chose the university because of its proximity to their parental home.
(parental home is correct. Example - New data from EU agency Eurofound shows a sharp increase in the number of young adults still living in their parental home)


So, there's only one way to interpret each of these sentences? What would you say if each of the five people lived in several houses?

You do not deal with the issue at all. There is no need to repeat the entire text from the OP but if you do, please do so more neatly.

@AnIELTSLearner You have to mention how many houses each of them own. OR you can make a general statement - Each of these five people lives in more than one house.

Yes, they live in houses [not apartments]. etc.

@AnIELTSLearner There's some slight ambiguity in "These five people live in a house," but native listeners have a strong lean towards the interpretation James Mathai provided. You would have to provide strong context to overcome it. "While they are very different, their separate dwellings have one similarity. Each of these five people lives in a house."

If I can't say anything more, what should I say when I want to talk about the type and when I don't want to talk about the type to avoid as much ambiguity as possible? I understand you might wonder why I can't add something, but sometimes it's a bit difficult and inconvenient to do so, especially in my essays.

It's still confusing to me because in the 1st and 2nd sentences, I want to talk about the type of accommodation and am advised to use "houses". However, in the 3rd example, where I also want to talk about types of parts of speech, @James said that "a" is correct. Finally, in the last example, it's not about the type of anything anymore, and James said "homes" is correct.

@AnIELTSLearner 'their parental home ' is correct. I have given another example in my answer.

@AnIELTSLearner For example 3 and 4, I would say that both versions (singular and plural) are correct and easily understood because neither creates extra ambiguity. The problem isn't a grammatically "proper" form, it's about what the statement is understood to contrast with.

@YonKuma If it's all about ambiguity, I wonder why people prefer 60% of the population live in houses over 60% of the population live in a house. I mean it's impossible for 60% of the population to live in one single house, so neither of the sentences is ambiguous, which should lead to them being equally preferred.

@AnIELTSLearner If you use different sentence construction, the rules differ. "60% of the population lives in houses" and "60% of the population lives in a house." Both are correct. To determine whether "percent" or % is singular or plural, look at the noun following it. If the next noun is a plural, use a plural verb; if it's singular, use a singular verb. The maximum glucose yield was 60%. Six percent of the pipes were rusty. More than 10% of that amount was allocated to planning.

Context:
You can't expect context from those two sentences. More would have to be said, either in a separate sentence or by adding something to them. I chose to add something. Of course, in speech where there is an ongoing conversation the context might be obvious but not here as written questions.

These five people live in houses, not apartments.
These five people live in a house down by the river.

However, the sentences are not ungrammatical as they are.
These five people live in houses.
These five people live in a house.

Sour grapes, anyone?

Upvoted. Your answer explained my question well. However, there's some more concern here, and I've expressed it under James's answer.

@AnIELTSLearner Well, I'm done. There really is nothing more for me to say.
